# How do I deploy Broadleaf 5.2 on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm working with Eclipse (photon) and the Broadleaf Community demo projects (site, admin, api, and core).

I've been able to run *site*, *admin*, and *api* on my local dev machine using the embedded Eclipse web server, and now I'm trying to deploy the site, admin, and api projects as a WAR on an AWS EC2 instance running Tomcat 8.5 (JVM 1.7).

I've followed the Broadleaf documentation:

- https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/tomcat
- https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/deploying-a-.war-file
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

plus *many* other Google search sites on the subject, but have had no success.  That and they're all from 2012 to 2015 and reference older versions (pre-Servlet 3.0) of BL.

I've even tried the "web.xml" approach:

- https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/5.3/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/using-a-web.xml

The WAR files being generated by Maven clean/install, (I've also tried "package"), don't look like the typical WAR file I've been used to:

Site: (ROOT.war)

```
META-INF
org
WEB-INF
```

Can someone give an example, or site, on how to deploy the BLC projects as a WAR on a Tomcat server?

The results I've getting are either a 404 on port 8443, or a blank page (when using the web.xml approach).

Sorry for the rather open/vague question, but with little-to-no documentation on this for BLC 5.2, I've turned to Stack Overflow for help.

Thanks

---

SiteApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SiteApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Configuration
    @EnableBroadleafSiteAutoConfiguration
    public static class BroadleafFrameworkConfiguration {}

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SiteApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany-community</groupId>
        <artifactId>boot-community-demo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>boot-community-demo-site</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Community Demo Site</name>
    <description>Web Module For Customized Broadleaf Commerce Site</description>

    <properties>
        <debug.port>8000</debug.port>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany-community</groupId>
            <artifactId>boot-community-demo-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-framework-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-boot-starter-solr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-boot-starter-hsql-database</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-boot-starter-database</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-thymeleaf3-presentation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.zhanhb</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, we figured it out.  I wanted to share the steps we took as it was a combination of steps/information from different sources (both BLC and Spring Boot sites).

---

**Step 1**:  The BLC codebase

Download the source from:  https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite

The file I used was "DemoSite-develop-5.2.x".

Unzip that in a location that your IDE can view/access.

---

**Step 2**:  The IDE (Eclipse in this case)

Follow the steps from this site (almost verbatim):

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/ide-setup/eclipse-setup

You should now have the *site*, *admin*, and *api* running locally, talking to the internal HSQL database.

- Admin: https: //localhost:8444/admin
- Site: https: //localhost:8443/
- API: https: //localhost:8445/api/v1/swagger-ui.html

---

**Step 3**:  Change to a MySQL database.

I pretty much followed these instructions, step-by-step (although I already had MySQL on my machine):

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/database-configuration/mysql#

---

**Step 4**:  BLC Project code/xml changes

It all starts with this link:

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/deploying-a-.war-file

Where you find out:

- Deploying a .war file
- Where is my web.xml?

Follow the steps in 87.1 of the following:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Basically:

- SpringBootServletInitializer in SiteApplication.java
- `<packaging>war</packaging>`
- The "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" lines in the pom.xml file.

Then I created a "web.xml" file, (although I'm not 100% sure I needed this as my servlet container is Servlet 3.1 and the BLC docs say all this web.xml configuration is now handled by annotations).

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/using-a-web.xml

Basically:

- BroadleafBootServletContextInitializer in SiteApplication.java

  - You'll note that we added "SpringBootServletInitializer" previously.
  - Now we replace that "SpringBootServletInitializer" with "BroadleafBootServletContextInitializer".
- Add the "web.xml" you'll find at the bottom of the page.
- Don't forget to change the "param-value" of the "context-param" tags to your correct package location.

---

**Step 5**: Tomcat changes

Another link that has most (if not all) of what you need:

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/tomcat

**/bin**

- New "setenv.sh" file containing:

  ```
  export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1536M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
  ```

**/conf**

- context.xml - Uncomment the following line

  ```
  `<Manager pathname="" />`
  ```
- *somenamehere*-keystore  (Needs to be generated, or grab the one in the BLC codebase)
- server.xml - Added the HTTPS Connector:

  ```
  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
          clientAuth="false" 
          keystoreFile="/path/to/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/conf/*somenamehere*.keystore" 
          keystorePass="BLCPassword" 
          keyPass="BLCPassword" 
          keystoreType="PKCS12"
          ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
          maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>



  Note that I had to add the "keystoreType" attribute due to 
  my keystore being in the PKCS12 format, as opposed to JKS.

  The "ciphers" attribute was added as I got an exception 
  complaining about the TLS I was using.
  ```
- tomcat-users.xml

  ```
  Added the following two lines:

  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="ReallyHardToGuessPW" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>

  I'm not sure if this step was 100% needed, but it allows me 
  to see the BLC projects within the "manager" app of Tomcat.
  ```

**/webapps**

- *host-manager* and *manager* apps

  ```
  In the "META-INF" of these apps I commented out both the "Valve" and "Manager" 
  tags in the "Context".

  This was extracted from this link:

      https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/

  (Look at "Step 6")

  This appears to be the only difference in my earlier attempts in 
  getting this running (pre-cry-for-SO-help), as yesterday and this 
  morning I had already performed all the steps in this post.
  ```

---

**Step 6**:  Maven Clean and Install

Within Eclipse, on each of the Site and Admin projects ("boot-community-site" and "boot-community-admin"), right-click and select *Run As >> Maven clean*.   Once that's finished run *Run As >> Maven install*.

Now in each project's "target" directory, you should see a WAR file, ("ROOT" for the Site project and "admin" for the Admin project).

---

**Step 7**: Start the Tomcat server

I started the Tomcat server with the resident apps (docs, examples, host-manager, manager, and ROOT) untouched.   I then hot-deployed the BLC "admin.war" and "ROOT.war" (site) to the Tomcat /webapps directory.

If this doesn't work for you, you can always stop the Tomcat server and place both ROOT.war and admin.war files in the /webapps directory. Then start the server.

If all goes well, viewing the "catalina.out" log file upon startup and you'll see an ASCII "Broadleaf Commerce" message scroll by, once for each BLC app, followed by a bunch of MySQL Hibernate messages.  The entire startup time seems to be about 4 minutes for both Site and Admin on an "m5.large" AWS EC2 instance.

I'll add to this as I think of what I've missed, but I now have BLC 5.2 running on a Tomcat 8.5 container.

Hope it's of some use to others out there with the same issue I had.

Comment: Pretty good guide, thanks for contributing! Just a quick note: you are right, the web.xml is unnecessary, and you can just extend from the SpringBootServletInitializer instead of the Broadleaf-specific one.

While they are mostly the same, some automatic servlet registrations that you can do with Spring `@Bean`s (namely, additional `ServletContextInitializer`s) cannot be done if you have a web.xml.

The only times you need a web.xml is if you get a really nasty error message about class transformation and that some classes were loaded too early. This does not happen in Tomcat >= 8.

Comment: I am getting the following error.

A component required a bean named 'blSessionFixationProtectionFilter' that could not be found. I checked it has the bean in one of the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

extremely helpful guide. I would like to add some things regarding **step 5** especially regarding spring security in a load balancer enviroment.

As the SSL will happen on the front end proxy, spring's security requiresSecure() might lead to an endless loop of redirects.

This is explained in depth [here](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/issues/49) and [here](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues/424)

An solution to this is:

After installing a ssl sertificate on the front end proxy include these two request headers in your .properties file:

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

There's no need to do a redirection from tomcat so you don't have to include the https connector in your server.xml as described on step 5.

Just add these two lines

> secure="true"

and

> scheme="https"

on the default connector of your tomcat's server.xml

```
<Connector port="hereisyourdefaultportofyourtomcat" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           secure="true"
           scheme="https" 
           />
```

Please note: the front-end proxy should send the above request headers. This happens by default in most cases.Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https)

Comment: @FaizFareed thanks. I hope this will save a lot of sleepless nights from people who try to figure it out.